# How to pull SQL row with multiple values comma separated into PowerShell array to be used in Get-ChildItem -exclude

Tags: sql, arrays, powershell

PowerShell newbie trying to figure out how to pull SQL row with multiple values comma separated  into PowerShell array to be used in  Get-ChildItem -exclude.

Please note I have the SQL portion working to where I can pull the values into PowerShell, but no matter what I have tried when I try to pass it to the -exclude option it thinks its just one name, versus comma separated names. I need help understanding how to pass the SQL row values into an array like this so it can be used properly with -exclude

View of hardcoded array that works
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fnsh.png

View of SQL table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNuKy.png

Code that gets it from SQL
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCP2P.png

View of PS code to remove folders using the -ExcludeFolder option https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfvlK.png

```
$ExcludeFolder = $row.ExcludeFolder

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Force -Exclude $excludeFolder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $CutDay} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
Write-Host "End Time:" (Get-Date)
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

SK

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: What does `$ExcludeFolder.GetType().Name` indicate about the data type? If it is a _string_ containing multiple names, you'll have to split it into an array of names.

Comment: The probability that someone will respond to your question will be greatly increased if the code, data, and error messages are in the question as text; not as pictures.

Comment: I've provided an answer, hopefully the OP comes back and reviews it. Rather than just take it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string in your $row.ExcludeFolders variable that reliably includes commas, you can use similar to the following to create an array:

[image: Comma Split]

You might then be able to pass the array as the -Exclude value